# Getting path of a selected item in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, directory

I am trying to get a path of a folder.

Here is what i got. This code checks latest file and selects it.

```
$dir = "C:\Users\%PATH%\downloads"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$latest.path
```

I need to check the path of the file to use it later on to move this folder using Move-Item function.

Comment: PowerShell does not use `%variablename%` syntax for environment variables. In PowerShell, we write `$env:variablename` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

**$latest.directoryname** will give you the path for the same and you can store that in the variable and use it in move-item whenever required.

```
$dir = "C:\Users\Ranadip\Downloads"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$destination= $latest.DirectoryName

Move-Item C:\scripts\temp* $destination
```